# MonoTouch Point[] to array of NSObject[]

Tags: ios, binding, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a binding the wraps `NSArray` as an array of NSObject (`NSObject[]`);

I have to set the property with a list of System.Drawing.Point[].

Unfortunately, I can't create an array of `NSObject` with items that don't inherit from `NSObject`.

How do I set this property with an array of `System.Drawing.Point`? I notice some runtime variables of `NSPoint`. How do I use that?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. For example:

```
PointF[] points = new PointF[] { new PointF(), new PointF() };
NSObject[] objects = new NSObject[]{NSObject.FromObject(points[0]), NSObject.FromObject(points[1])};
```

FromObject method has parameter which is object type, so you can allocate anything.